# Suspicious typecast of RawByteString to PWideChar

Tags: delphi, utf-8, libxml2, delphi-xe5

I use libxml2 (http://www.xmlsoft.org/) for reading/writing xml-files in my Delphi code. libxml2 uses UTF-8 encoding for all strings.

For example, the function xmlsavefile is defined in libxml2 as

```
int xmlSaveFile (const char * filename, xmlDocPtr cur)
```

In the libxml2 Delphi bindings this function is translated to

```
const LIBXML2_SO = 'libxml2-2.dll';
function xmlSaveFile(const FileName: PChar; cur: xmlDocPtr) : Longint; cdecl; external LIBXML2_SO;
```

This function can be used as

```
var FileName : string;
xmlSaveFile(PChar(Utf8Encode(FileName)), doc);
```

This seems to work without any problems and has been tested with various languages including Chinese. However, I get the compiler warning

*Suspicious typecast of RawByteString to PWideChar*

As everything works fine I tend to ignore this warning. Nevertheless,

- Can I get rid of this warning?
- Do I have to expect any issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Delphi binding that you are using is outdated, likely written before Delphi 2009, when `(P)Char` was still an alias for `(P)AnsiChar`.  From Delphi 2009 onward, `(P)Char` is now an alias for `(P)WideChar` instead.  So the compiler warning is correct - you really are typecasting the `RawByteString` returned by `UTF8Encode()`, which is an `AnsiChar`-based string, to a `PWideChar` instead of to a `PAnsiChar`.

You need to update the binding (or get an updated version, or find a different binding, that has already made the update) to use `PAnsiChar` explicitly everywhere that `libxml2` uses `char*` strings, eg:

```pascal
function xmlSaveFile(const FileName: PAnsiChar; cur: xmlDocPtr) : Longint; cdecl; external LIBXML2_SO;
```

And then update your code to match:

```pascal
var FileName : string;
xmlSaveFile(PAnsiChar(UTF8Encode(FileName)), doc);
```

```pascal
var FileName : string;
xmlSaveFile(PAnsiChar(UTF8String(FileName)), doc);
```

```pascal
var FileName : UTF8String;
xmlSaveFile(PAnsiChar(FileName), doc);
```

Comment: The latest version of the Delphi bindings for libxml2 I could find is about 10 years old, so the development seems to be suspended.

Comment: libxml2.pas defines
type xmlCharPtr = PAnsiChar;
but this is used only inconsequently and not everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is in the declaration of the imported function:

```
function xmlSaveFile(const FileName: PChar; cur: xmlDocPtr) : Longint; cdecl; 
  external LIBXML2_SO;
```

This function accepts an 8 bit UTF8 encoded filename. That can be seen from the C code which declares the filename parameter as `const char *`.

Change the code to:

```
function xmlSaveFile(const FileName: PAnsiChar; cur: xmlDocPtr) : Longint; cdecl; 
  external LIBXML2_SO;
```

And then pass:

```
PAnsiChar(Utf8Encode(FileName))
```

Comment: Worth noting that `Utf8Encode` returns a `RawByteString` type which is defined as `RawByteString = type AnsiString($ffff);`, ie: a code-page agnostic AnsiString.  The warning is caused by the implicit cast of a single byte string type to a multi-byte `PChar` type.

Comment: Note that `UTF8Encode()` has been deprecated since D2009, you can simply typecast to `UTF8String` instead: `PAnsiChar(UTF8String(FileName))`